# Fixing an error related to a .sty file

Tags: environments, styles

first, excuse me if I'm not using the right technical terms. I am not an expert in LaTeX.
I am using Overleaf to write some .tex files and I have a .sty file that contains environments (like the one called "correction").
When I compile, every time I make a \begin{correction}, I get the error :

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/correction' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

It sends me to a particular line (line **39**). But I don't really see where the error is. I tried to understand, to compare with the previous paragraphs, if there's something missing.. But I didn't find anything.

The code is working actually. I do have the "correction" environment I want, despite the error, but I'd like to understand where this error comes from. I have no idea what `tcb/correction` means, in the error message.

Here is the MWE and the complete .sty file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[sujet]{pas-correction}
\usepackage[correction]{pas-correction}


  \begin{document}

    \bigskip

% Ex1
\textbf{Exercice 1}\\

The question..


\begin{correction}
  The solution..
\end{correction}


\end{document}
```

The .sty file (pas-correction.sty)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                               %
%        pas-correction  v1.02  encodage : UTF8                 %
%                                                               %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                               %
%           Créé par Stéphane PASQUET                           %
%                                                               %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Objet : créer un document avec ou sans le corrigé
% Informations générales
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{pas-correction}[2020/07/14]
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox} %salma:[many]
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,magazine}
\newif\if@correction
\newif\if@sujet
\DeclareOption{correction}{\@correctiontrue}
\DeclareOption{sujet}{\@sujettrue}
\ProcessOptions

% Styles par défaut



\newcount\@visibility
\@visibility\z@

%----------> Portion de code due à  Christian Tellechea (alias "un bon petit")
\newwrite\sav@body
\newcount\sav@cnt
\def\grab@body{\begingroup\sav@cnt\z@\loop
   \ifnum\sav@cnt<\@cclvi\catcode\sav@cnt12 \advance\sav@cnt\@ne\repeat
   \newlinechar`\^^M \grab@body@i}
\begingroup\edef\tmp@namedef{\endgroup\long\def\noexpand\grab@body@i##1\expandafter\@gobble\string\\\detokenize{end{document}}}
\tmp@namedef{%
   \immediate\openout\sav@body\jobname.sav
   \immediate\write\sav@body{#1}\immediate\closeout\sav@body
   \endgroup\if@sujet\maketitlesubject\input\jobname.sav\fi\if@correction\advance\@visibility\@ne\if@sujet\newpage\fi\maketitlecorrection\input\jobname.sav\fi
   \end{document}
   \ingnorespaces}
\g@addto@macro\document\grab@body
%----------> Fin du code


% Environnement "correction"


\newsavebox{\@correc@box}
\newenvironment{correction}
{% 
    \ifnum\@visibility=1
        \begin{tcolorbox}[correction,title=Corrigé,breakable, width=\textwidth, enhanced]
    \else 
        \begin{lrbox}{\@correc@box}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \fi 
} 
{%

    \ifnum\@visibility=1
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \else
        \end{minipage}
        \end{lrbox}
    \fi
}

% macros  pour les titres
% \setcounter{count@exo}{0}%%salma
% \setcounter{thecounter}{0}%%salma
\def\@newtitlesubject{}
\newcommand\newtitlesubject[1]{\def\@newtitlesubject{#1}}
\def\@newtitlecorrection{}
\newcommand\newtitlecorrection[1]{\def\@newtitlecorrection{#1}}

%\newcommand\titlesubject[1]{\edef\@title@subject@name{#1}}
%\newcommand\maketitlesubject{\ifx\@newtitlesubject\@empty\begin{center}\begin{tcolorbox}[title]\@title@subject@name\end{tcolorbox}\end{center}\else\@newtitlesubject\fi}
%\newcommand\titlecorrection[1]{\edef\@title@correction@name{#1}}
%\newcommand\maketitlecorrection{\ifx\@newtitlesubject\@empty\begin{center}\begin{tcolorbox}[title]\@title@correction@name\end{tcolorbox}\end{center}\else\@newtitlecorrection\fi}
\newcommand\newpageforsubject{\ifnum\@visibility=0\newpage\fi}
\newcommand\newpageforcorrection{\ifnum\@visibility=1\newpage\fi}
\newcommand{\dottedlinesubject}{\ifnum\@visibility=0\dotfill\fi}

% suppression du fichier auxiliaire

\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write18{erase \jobname.sav}}
```

Comment: the sty is faulty. There is a better version here https://www.mathweb.fr/euclide/les-packages-personnels-latex-stephane-pasquet/, but you will have to add to the document a `\titlecorrection{something}` to compile without error.

Comment: Thank you. First, I tried to uncomment the line containing \titlecorrection. But the problem persisted.
So I copy-pasted the file in the link you gave me, but there's another error now.

Comment: yes as I wrote, you will have to add `\titlecorrection{something}` to your document. The package expects that.

Comment: Okay I tried to write simple \titlecorrection{something}, and no more errors! I'll edit it of course, but thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't keep the same box style as the one I had. I tried to copy/paste what I thought was relevant, I also deleted what I thought was the description of the unwanted "style", but it didn't work. I still have errors.

Comment: Any help please? It worked with the original "correction box style" only. Can you please help?

Comment: sorry but I have no idea what you did or what you want to achieve. But stop to edit and break the style. If you want to redefine something do it in your document.